# Templating business object collections for use in a DataGrid

Tags: wpf, xaml, templates, styles

Assuming the following two fictitious classes:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public decimal Salary { get; set; }
    public string SSN { get; set; }
}

public class People: ObservableCollection<Person> {}
```

Suppose I want to display an instance of a People object in a DataGrid with the following considerations:

- Id should be read only
- Salary should be formatted as a currency
- SSN should not be displayed

I know how to do some pretty simple stuff with styles and templates, but I can't seem to find any good info on using them to dictate how a DataGrid should display data.  An example of how to do the above would be great, and any links to good resources on this topic would be appreciated.

Comment: Or is what I'm asking here even possible?

Comment: Check my answer, it's not about templates or styles, but I think this might be useful to you.

Comment: I found some info along the lines of what I'm looking for here: http://www.paulstovell.com/dynamic-datagrid.  I don't quite want to do what he's doing, but I think I may be able to figure out what I want using info gleaned out of his blog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the DisplayAttribute in the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations namespace. You can specify if the field is displayed or not, the column header, the column order, etc. You can use many annotations in each field.

In your example you would need something like:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

public class Person
{
    [Editable(false)]
    [Display(Name = "Person ID", Order = 0)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(30, ErrorMessage = "too long!")]
    [Display(Name = "First Name", Order = 10)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last Name", Order = 20)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString="C")]
    [Display(Name = "$/year", Order = 30)]
    public decimal Salary { get; set; }

    [Display(AutoGenerateField=false)]
    public string SSN { get; set; }
}
```

This information will be used anytime you generate fields automatically. You can even create groups of fields to group them into tabs, etc.

Hope this is the answer you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks Hannish.  This is still not quite what I was looking for but very close.  The idea is right, except that using this method restricts you to a single 'template'.  I may want another template for the same class that displays differently.  I'll probably mark this the answer if no one else steps up though because it's definitely the next best thing.

Comment: Thank you Brandon. Display attributes only apply when autogenerating something (like columns), you can still have a template that displays everything in a different way. If you can't use XAML templates, and also need different displays for the same class, I'm afraid you'll have to do it dynamically as you said in the comment for the other answer. If you come up with another idea please post it! Regards.

Comment: Not really, but it's not super important at the moment so I will go ahead and mark this the answer since it's close.

Comment: Ok, thank you. If you come up with something in the future please let me know, its interesting.

Comment: Although this isn't exactly what I wanted, I think the pieces I need to accomplish what I was after could be gleaned from this blog post: http://www.paulstovell.com/dynamic-datagrid.  Maybe when I have some time in the future I'll figure it out and post another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can set the `AutoGenerateColumns` to `False` and specify the columns manually which you want to show and can customize it as per your needs something like this -

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding People}"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Id}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding FirstName}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding LastName}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Salary, StringFormat=C}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: The idea is to have a DataGrid that can display a variety of Business Object collection types, so hardcoding the number of columns and properties they are bound to is out.  However the current solution I'm working on does this dynamically in code.  What I was really after though is a way to create styles/templates for various types to be displayed that the DataGrid will pick up on.  At this point, it seems like this is something no one is really even thinking about.  Whether that's just because I'm going in the wrong direction in my thinking or not I have yet to determine for sure though.